# How to display hr horizontally with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When using flexbox for styling, if the parent container is set to `display: flex` it will cause the `<hr />` to be displayed vertically instead of horizontally.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `flex-grow: 1` or `width: 100%` so it will grow to match the width of the parent. You probably want to use that in combination with `flex-wrap: wrap` on `.container` if you plan on putting more flex children in `.container`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

hr {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* width: 100%; */ /* or this */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this is that default value of `align-items` is `stretch` so `hr` will get the same height as largest element in `flex-container` or in this case `h2`. And default value for `justify-content` is `flex-start` so width of `hr` is 0.

Easy way to fix this is to use `flex-wrap: wrap` on parent element and `flex: 0 0 100%` on `hr`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
hr {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - accepted answer didn't work for me.