# Using flex to make the horizontal line vertical

Tags: html, css

I have read that inside a flex container if we give an **hr** tag [it will become vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986500/how-to-display-hr-horizontally-with-flex). I have tried the same, but not able to achieve. Am I missing something here ?

```css
.outer-div {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.inner-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <div class="details-div">
      <i class="fas fa-band-aid">I</i>
      <span>Get Details</span>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="call-div">
      <i class="fas fa-band-aid">I</i>
      <span>Call Customer Care</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What effect are you trying to acheive. That's not what `hr` are for.

Comment: Voting to close. There's actually no question here.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* working. Your element is just so short that it appears as a dot.

```css
.outer-div {
  background-color: pink;
}

.inner-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <div class="details-div">
      <i class="fas fa-band-aid"></i>
      <span>Get Details</span>
    </div>
    
    <hr />
    
    <div class="call-div">
      <i class="fas fa-band-aid"></i>
      <span>Call Customer Care</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It does, the problem is, that the `margin` on the `<hr/>` makes it almost a dot.
You could set your `margin: 0` on the `<hr/>` to achieve expected behavior

> The reason for this is that default value of `align-items` is `stretch` so `<hr>` will get the same height as largest element in flex-container [...].

Quoted from [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986500/how-to-display-hr-horizontally-with-flex)

```css
.outer-div {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.inner-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

hr {
 margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <div class="details-div">
      <i class="fas fa-band-aid">I</i>
      <span>Get Details</span>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="call-div">
      <i class="fas fa-band-aid">I</i>
      <span>Call Customer Care</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Approach #1 : `transform: rotate(90deg)`

One approach to achieving a vertical `<hr>` is simply to apply:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.inner-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.inner-div hr {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-div">
  <div class="details-div">Get Details</div>
  <hr />
  <div class="call-div">Call Customer Care</div>
</div>
```

---

### Approach #2 : Explicit `height` and `width`

Another approach is to declare exlicit dimensions for your `<hr>`:

- `width: 0;`
- `height: 120px`

**Working Example:**

```css
.inner-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.inner-div hr {
  width: 0px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-div">
  <div class="details-div">Get Details</div>
  <hr />
  <div class="call-div">Call Customer Care</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for do it

```
.className{
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```